# Need a query to show mismatched data on comparing tables

Tags: sql, mysql, plsql, compare, plsqldeveloper

I have 2 tables: tab_Def and tab_Prod with same columns and same data.
Table tab_Def is a default table that has model data. Table tab_Prod is a production table on which some updates may be made but need to match table tab_Def by the end of the day. Some data in these tables in one column are duplicate but differ when clubbed with another column like so:

tab_Def:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | ABC |
| 102 | ABC |
| 101 | XYZ |

tab_Prod: (post updates)

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| -101 | ABC |
| 102 | ABC |
| -101 | XYZ |

I have the below query but it compares each line with all the rows and instead of only the mismatched data rows shows all the  rows where the digits don't match.

```
select a.col_1, a.col_2, b.col_1
from tab_Def a, tab_Prod b
where a.col_2=b.col_2
and a.col_1<>b.col_1
group by a.col_2, a.col_1, b.col_1
order by a.col_1, b.col_1, a.col_2;
```

I need to compare the two tables and get the mismatched rows (col_1 -101) in results like below:

Expected Results:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | ABC | -101 |
| 101 | XYZ | -101 |

How should I edit my query?

Comment: Is there not a unique key common to both tables? You should not rely on the order in which unordered sets are returned. And why have copies of the data in the first place? This sounds like a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your data example this looks simple as ,

```
select td.col_1,
       td.col_2,
       tp.col_1
from tab_Def td 
inner join tab_Prod tp on td.col_2=tp.col_2
where tp.col_1 = concat('-',td.col_1);
```

Result,

```
col_1   col_2   col_1
 101     ABC    -101
 101     XYZ    -101
```

Another option , in the tab_Prod we will replace all non numeric values with ''.

```
select td.col_1,
       td.col_2,
       tp.col_1
from tab_Def td 
inner join tab_Prod tp on td.col_2=tp.col_2
where td.col_1 <> tp.col_1
and   td.col_1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(tp.col_1, '[^0-9]+', '');
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/gDHWXibY)

**Edit**

> I need the table to be aligned sequentially and then compared so the
> col_1 from both tables are compared with col_2 being common. So I need
> row 1: 101,ABC from tab_Def to be compared with row 1: -101,ABC from
> tab_Prod

```
with tab_Def as (
  select col_1,
         col_2,
         row_number() over() as row_num
  from tab_Def
), tab_Prod as (
  select col_1,
         col_2,
         row_number() over() as row_num
  from tab_Prod
)   select td.col_1,
           td.col_2,
           tp.col_1
    from tab_Def td 
    inner join tab_Prod tp on td.row_num=tp.row_num
    where td.col_1 <> tp.col_1
```

[See updated example](https://dbfiddle.uk/InZg99u6)

Comment: Thank you, but this still gives me extra rows in the result because it is comparing each row from tab_Def with each row from tab_Prod. 
I need the table to be aligned sequentially and then compared so the col_1 from both tables are compared with col_2 being common.
So I need row 1: 101,ABC from tab_Def to be compared with row 1: -101,ABC from tab_Prod and then give the result showing these rows as their col_1 does not match.
Similarly, row 2: 102,ABC from tab_Def to be compared with row 2: 102,ABC from tab_Prod and this row should not show up in the results because their col_1 matches.